# Undefined reference to type traits

Tags: c++, linker, operator-overloading

I'm creating a CUDA/C++ complex numbers/functions library. In particular, I have defined my own implementations of complex types `int2_`, `float2_` and `double2_` in `ComplexTypes.cuh` and `ComplexTypes.cu` files and I have the following file structure:

**Result_Types.cuh** - Type traits file - Defines `result_type_promotion`,

```
/*************/
/* PROMOTION */
/*************/
template <typename, typename> struct result_type_promotion;
....
template<> struct result_type_promotion< int2_, float2_ >   { typedef float2_ strongest; };
....

/*************/
/* FUNCTIONS */
/*************/

template <typename> struct result_type_root_functions;
....
```

**Operator_Overloads.cuh**

```
template<typename T0, typename T1> __host__ __device__ typename result_type_promotion<T0, T1>::strongest operator+(T0, T1);
....
```

**Operator_Overloads.cu** - Overloads of common operations between complex numbers

```
#include "ComplexTypes.cuh"                                     
#include "Result_Types.cuh"
#include "Operator_Overloads.cuh"
....
__host__ __device__ result_type_promotion<int2_,float2_>::strongest         add(const int2_ a, const float2_ b)  { result_type_promotion<int2_,float2_>::strongest          c; c.c.x = a.c.x+b.c.x; c.c.y = a.c.y+b.c.y; return c; }
....
__host__ __device__ result_type_promotion<int2_,float2_>::strongest operator+(const int2_ a,const float2_ b)  { return add(a,b); }
```

**Function_Overloads.cuh**

```
template<typename T0> typename result_type_root_functions<T0>::root_functions                   Asinh(T0);
```

**Function_Overloads.cu** - Overloads of functions on complex numbers

```
#include "ComplexTypes.cuh"                                     
#include "Result_Types.cuh"
#include "Operator_Overloads.cuh"

__host__ __device__ result_type_root_functions<int>::root_functions         Asinh(const int a)              { return asinh((float)a); }
....
```

The above files, except for the type traits file which is dealt with as an include file, are compiled on the command line using `nvcc` and `cl` to form a `.lib` file.

Unfortunately, when I compile the main function which includes

```
#include "ComplexTypes.cuh"
#include "Result_Types.cuh"
#include "Operator_Overloads.cuh"
#include "Function_Overloads.cuh"
```

I have linkage errors of the type

```
Error   247 error : Undefined reference to '_ZplIN2BB5int2_ENS0_7float2_EEN21result_type_promotionIT_T0_E9strongestES4_S5_' in '...Test.lib'
```

Please, note that:

1. Only the complex types `int2_`, `float2_` and `double2_` are in a `BB` namespace, but I'm adding `using namespace BB;` in all the definition files;
2. The problem arises when I'm using `+` in the `Function_Overloads.cu` file; if I'm not using `+`, then no problem arises;
3. I (surprisingly) can use `+` in the `main` function without receiving any linkage error.

*Any idea to solve this problem?*

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Following billz suggestions, I have solved the problem by adding explicit instantiations in the `Function_Overloads.cu` file, like

```
__host__ __device__ result_type_promotion<int,int2_>::strongest operator+(const int a,const int2_ b);
....
```

Comment: where is `operator+` defined?

Comment: @billz In the `Operator_Overloads.cu` file, see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> _ZplIN2BB5int2_ENS0_7float2_EEN21result_type_promotionIT_T0_E9strongestES4_S5_

decoded by `c++filt` becomes:

```
result_type_promotion<BB::int2_, BB::float2_>::strongest operator+<BB::int2_, BB::float2_>(BB::int2_, BB::float2_)
```

Which means your compiler can't find function definition, you need to implement it in header file.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out that as well as the use of `c++filt`. What is not very clear to me is why, once created the static library, can I use the `+` operator in the `main` function but I have no visibility of such an overload inside a function defined in `Function_Overloads.cu`. Could you suggest any test that I can make to solve this problem (provided that this problem _has_ a solution :-) )?

Comment: this link may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: I have added explicit instantiations (not implementations) in the `Function_Overloads.cu` file and this solved the problem. Following your link, I understand that in my original version in the compilation unit of `Function_Overloads.cu` there was no instantiation to be subsequently linked and I also understand why now explicit instantiations solve the problem. However, I do not understand why in the `main` function everything works without explicit instantiations.

Comment: By the way, there is an online demangler: [c++filtjs](http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/).